# Routing between two interfaces

Tags: iptables, routing

I have a network 10.0.0.0/24, a gateway with ip 10.0.0.1. On the gateway there are two interfaces.

```
eth0        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:a1:24:2d  
            inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fea1:242d/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:221 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:939 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:26698 (26.0 KiB)  TX bytes:65901 (64.3 KiB)

eth1        Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:18:75:46  
            inet addr:192.168.56.102  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe18:7546/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:898138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:159141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
            RX bytes:1044694113 (996.2 MiB)  TX bytes:9919636 (9.4 MiB)
```

I want to do routing from eth1 where received traffic to eth0, interface for internal network and vice versa. Gateway do ip forwarding and. I have set this in sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1.
```

I tried this with iptables but doesn't work:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Share the gateway's routing table (`ip r sh` or `route -n`) plus one of the client's routing tables. Do you have any other active firewall rules? Sharing them might help too. What happens of you ping a host from a client that is not in the client's subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you want.
I assuming that your eth1 is a gateway for the 192.168.56.0 networks.
Please try:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.56.0/24 -j SNAT --to 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: There's no indication NAT is needed here. Although it may work, it's very likely that it's not the best solution.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not very sure what he want.